# A definition of the functional $f\to\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)f \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) $, involving good functions $f$ and the Möbius function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory, absolute-convergence, mobius-function

I would like to create a definition, is a conditional definition since the behaviour of arithmetic functions like to the Möbius function $\mu(n)$ depends on the veracity of the Riemann Hypothesis, that is an unsolved problem.

Any case I would like to know how create a definition with mathematical meaning. And as I am saying we are on assumption of the Riemann Hypothesis, because I believe that my definition requires this hypothesis to deduce the absolute convergence of a functional, that is its definition.

The definition is for the functional $\mathcal{F}$, from the set of entire functions (or you can do a restriction to analytic functions on an open subset of the complex plane $A(\Omega)$) to $\mathbb{C}$, *defined by the rule* $$f\to\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)f \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) .$$

> **An example.** A particular value of our funtional $\mathcal{F}$, is given by $$\mathcal{F}(\operatorname{erf})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n) \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) ,$$ where $\operatorname{erf}$ is the [Erf function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html), and as was said for integeres $n\geq 1$, we are denoting by $\mu(n)$ the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). Then we find that RHS is absolutely convergent, thus this particular value for the entire function $\operatorname{erf}$ is defined as a complex number.

I presume that our functional $\mathcal{F}$ will be linear (are easy justifications).

> **Question.** How do you create a/this definition, rigurously, for the functional $\mathcal{F}$ that I've evoked, on assumption of the Riemann Hypothesis? **Many thanks.**

Thus I believe that is required state the domain of our functional as a subset of the linear space of entire functions, (show that is linear) and show that is defined by absolute convergence, using the asymptotic behaviour of means of the Möbius function (I presume that it is the way, and this is the reason for which is neccesary to state that we are on assumption of the Riemann Hypothesis, but if you know how create a *definition* without this assumption you can add it to your answer).

If there are inaccuracies in my previous words please tell me. My purpose is to know how create this definition in mathematics.

Comment: My purpose is the curiosity to know how create a definition in mathematics, based in previous ideas. I hope someone is encouraged to tell us how to define an operator of this kind. Such definition could be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your functional is independent of the Riemann hypothesis.

First we note that since there are infinitely many primes, we have $\lvert\mu(n)\rvert = 1$ for infinitely many $n$, and since $f\bigl(\frac{1}{n}\bigr) \to f(0)$ by continuity, the series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(n)f\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)\tag{1}$$

can only converge for functions $f$ with $f(0) = 0$.

If $f$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ and defined at $\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, with $f(0) = 0$, then on $U$ we can write

$$f(z) = f'(0)\cdot z + z^2g(z)$$

with a holomorphic function $g$. There is an $r > 0$ such that $\overline{D_r(0)} = \{ z\in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant r\} \subset U$, and since $\overline{D_r(0)}$ is compact, $g$ is bounded there, say $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant K$ for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant r$. Since

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$

is absolutely convergent if and only if $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, the series

$$\sum_{n = \lceil 1/r\rceil}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}g\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)$$

is absolutely convergent, and hence $(1)$ is absolutely convergent if and only if

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(n) f'(0)\frac{1}{n}$$

is absolutely convergent, that is, if and only if $f'(0) = 0$.

To get an absolutely convergent series $(1)$, we thus have to require $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$. However, the series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$$

is conditionally convergent (to $0$), and so the series $(1)$ is (conditionally) convergent for all holomorphic $f$ with $f(0) = 0$.

Since only the values of $f$ at the real points $\frac{1}{n}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ are used in $(1)$, we can define the functional $\mathcal{F}$ for continuous functions $g\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ with $g(0) = 0$ that are twice continuously differentiable on $[0,r]$ for some $r \in (0,1]$. The corresponding series will then be conditionally convergent if $g'(0) \neq 0$, and absolutely convergent if $g'(0) = 0$, by essentially the same argument as above.

However, for analytic functions whose Maclaurin series converges absolutely at $1$ (in particular, functions that are holomorphic at least on some disk $D_r(0)$ with $r > 1$), we can get a nice alternate form of the functional. Namely, with the Maclaurin expansion

$$f(z) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k z^k$$

we obtain

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(n)f\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(n)\Biggl(\frac{a_1}{n} + \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{n^k}\Biggr) \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(n)\frac{a_1}{n} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\mu(n)\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{n^k} \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\mu(n)\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{n^k} \\
&= \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} a_k \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^k} \\
&= \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{\zeta(k)}
\end{align}

since

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$$

for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, and the change of order of summation is legitimate by absolute convergence:

$$\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\lvert \mu(n)a_k\rvert}{n^k} \leqslant \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \lvert a_k\rvert \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^k} = \sum_{k = 2}^\infty \zeta(k)\lvert a_k\rvert \leqslant 2\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \lvert a_k\rvert < +\infty$$

since we assumed the Maclaurin series converges absolutely at $1$.

Since $\frac{1}{\zeta}$ has a zero at $1$, we can also write

$$\mathcal{F}(f) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!\zeta(k)}$$

for these functions. In that form, we have a natural extension of the functional to holomorphic functions whose Maclaurin series converges absolutely at $1$ even when $f(0) \neq 0$:

$$\tilde{\mathcal{F}}(f) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!\zeta(k)}.$$

Comment: Many thanks, I will need some hours to understand your very nice statements, and it seems one of the best answers that one can read in this site. Many thanks for share all justifications and the shape of your functional!

Comment: From some of your definitions (the definition for wich the calculations will be fesibles), please could tell me next week hints/how to calculate the norm of the operator $\mathcal{F}$? I am asking well for the case of continuous functions, with $g(0)=0$, $g'(0)=0$ and twice continuously differentiable on the segment, or well the second case, the analytic functions whose Maclaurin series converges absolutely at $1$ (or its particular case). If you can do it, many thanks and good week.

Comment: The norm of $\mathcal{F}$ depends on the norm we use on the domain. For the analytic function whose Maclaurin series converges absolutely at $1$, a natural choice of the norm is $\lVert f\rVert = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \lvert a_n\rvert$, where $f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$. Then we have $\lVert \mathcal{F}\rVert = 1$ and $\lVert\tilde{\mathcal{F}}\rVert = 2$, since $\zeta(0) = -1/2$ and $\zeta(k) > 1$ and $\zeta(k) \to 1$. (Consider $f_m(z) = z^m$ for $\mathcal{F}$ and a constant function for $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$).

Comment: For $\{ f \in C^2([0,1]) : f(0) = f'(0) = 0\}$, there's not such a natural norm on the domain, but $\lVert f\rVert = \max \{ \lvert f''(t)\rvert : t \in [0,1]\}$ is a pretty good norm for that space. I'm not sure what $\lVert\mathcal{F}\rVert$ would be in that setting. $\zeta(2)$ is an upper bound, since in the notation of the answer we have $g(t) = f''(\vartheta\cdot t)$. Taking $f(t) = t^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha \geqslant 2$ gives a lower bound of $\dfrac{1}{\alpha\zeta(\alpha)}$.

Comment: You're very kind/friendly, I read carefuly your remarks and refresh my functional analysis.